Open api specs for a kafka consumer listner api
I have a Kafka consumer api in spring boot, so no specific calls are made to it as it is a Kafka consumer listener.Can such an api have open api specifications defined or documented?
As api has no specific end point, not sure what can be defined in an oas3 specs file for it.

AsyncApi is a specification for the Kafka events. As you've said, since Kafka is not HTTP based, you would not use OpenAPI for it
